# 502 response coming from errors in Google Cloud LoadBalancer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, load-balancing

I'm using Google App Engine Flexible env (already migrated to env:flex) with python 3.4 runtime.

Over last month, i noticed multiple times(but less than 5% of requests) that i or automated processes, get a 502 from the server (Bad Gateway). Couldn't reproduce it locally and couldn't find any trace for it under **GAE** service logs. 
But looking for 502 error across all services, i realized that they come from Cloud HTTP Load Balancer service.

Going over the jsonPayload of these 502 errors, i see this reason:

> statusDetails: "failed_to_pick_backend"
>   @type:"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry"

I don't have a custom load-balancer service from GCP, i never had to deal with it till now. The GAE VM instance is consistently below 10% of CPU Utilization

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: This question seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305122/some-502-errors-in-gcp-http-load-balancing

Comment: It does sounds related, but again, as am using GAE, i don't have control over the load balancer

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I figured it out, but not by digging into the logs.
The issue was that there were requests to the server that called a function that does time.sleep(something), and doing that too much (like for waiting for an Ajax request) caused the load balancer error.
Once i removed this function, the errors disappeared.

Comment: Did you have manual scaling set in your app.yaml?