# GCP load balancer 502 server error and "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client" IIS 10

Tags: iis, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, http-error, iis-10

I have GCP load balancer with 4 IIS 10 web servers. Sporadically it comes with **502-Server error**. In the logs it shows it is because of **backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client**. I have read thru the article https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ and it says keepalive timout need to be set to 620 seconds for nginx and apache.  How do I do the same in IIS 10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured this out after raising a ticket google cloud team. I am putting it here so that others can benefit.

**Step 1 : Set the timeouts in Google Cloud Load Balancer**

There are two timeout settings in Google cloud load balancer.

1. **Timeout** and
2. **Connection draining timeout.**

See the screenshot below.
[image: Load balancer settings]

Both the above settings need to be the same. In our case, there are a number of long running requests and it is set to 1800 seconds.

**Step 2: Set the connection timeout in IIS 20 second greater than the load balancer setting**

Under IIS Site name - go to **Advanced settings** and then set the **Connection Time-out** value to 20 seconds more than the load balancer timeout. In my case 1820.

[image: IIS Settings]

The idea is that  the IIS connection should not timeout before load balancer. If it times out then it may leads to **backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client** error.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this in [web.config](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd632626.aspx) as execution time out attribute in http runtime by default when you set keep alive it sets time out to 120 seconds .If still doesn’t work then may be there is proxy server between your request response process . You have to check that proxy server time out.

I faced the same scenario in gcp and I have setted everything in load balancer level but did not work . Then I found that there was an proxy server between our process . Let me know if you can tell in more detail

Comment: What is that web.config settings and it should be applicable to IIS 10.

Comment: You might need to check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/136306/what-is-the-iis7-default-keepalive-time#tab-top) thread, where they discussed about changing the Keep-alive value on IIS. See if that helps you