# GCP HTTPS Loadbalancer request gets timedout after 300 seconds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timeout, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I'm using GCP Loadbalancer for accessing my web applications. There are some cases where my service might take sometime to give the response back (more than 300 seconds). When I check with GCP settings I saw two timeouts (**Connection Timeout** and **Connection Draining Timeout**) as mentioned in the below link,

[GCP load balancer 502 server error and "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client" IIS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020779/gcp-load-balancer-502-server-error-and-backend-connection-closed-before-data-se)

Even after increasing the time out, still my requests are getting timedout at 300 seconds. Is there any other time out that has to be configured? Or do I need to configure TCP for the HTTPS GCP Loadbalancer which I have now.

**Operating System :** Windows Server 2012
**Web Server:** WildFly

Please give some suggestions.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your use case - whatever might be relevan (OS, web-server, etc). The more the better.

Comment: I have updated can you suggest me?

Comment: Did you try to change the default timeout in the WildFly ? Is your application ovveriding that (it can) ?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 502 means that the thing your LB was connected to -- your backend service -- disconnected suddenly, so the problem is not between the client and LB, but between LB and your service.  You'd see this picture if your backendservice crashes.  Since it's happening exactly 300 after you start your request it is likely that there's some other timeout in play, but it's somewhere in LB <-> backend service.

[EDIT]
I had a similar issue when our LB was timing out after 300 seconds.  When I changed the timeout setting in the Web UI it was getting reset back to 300 seconds after a minutes or so.  It turned out it was set by our Kubernetes -- when one configures `BackendConfig` a special controller is installed that keeps track of the timeout setting and one needs to change the timeout value appying new `BackendConfig` config, i.e., not in Web UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing error configuring internal load balancer please confider checking your firewall rule. When an internal load balancer is created it needs to have a proxy , ensure that this proxy is whitelisted in your firewall rule. I had similar timeout issue which got fixed by adding a firewall rule.